# Is JRuby ready for production?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby

I just found out about **JRuby**, and I like the idea of running Ruby on Rails and being able to call Java libraries.

I would like to know about some experiences with running enterprise production applications in JRuby. Are stability and performance acceptable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a blog post from a company that created a cross-platform, multithreaded, desktop simulation application with JRuby.  I think their success indicates JRuby is ready for enterprise production applications.

http://spin.atomicobject.com/2009/01/30/ruby-for-desktop-applications-yes-we-can

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's pretty fast too.  I'm not sure how they all compare now, but with the new dynamic invoke bytecode added to the JVM, it should become by far the fastest implementation available.

Groovy and Grails should also get a big speed boost from this pretty soon.

Answer (score 1):

We're using it at our company on a large project. The major problem we find is that there isn't as large of a community built around the technology as say Java or .Net. Which makes recruiting difficult.

Answer (score 0):

JRuby is among the fastest Ruby implementations right now and definitely production ready.

Here's some "success stories" from jruby.org:

http://wiki.jruby.org/wiki/Success_Stories

Answer (score 0):

Jason Seifer says yes. His presentation on Ruby VM's is on InfoQ.

A look at the different Ruby virtual machines (JRuby, MagLev, IronRuby, Rubinius, MacRuby) and how to choose what fits best within the enterprise.

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/seifer-ruby-vm-comparison

Answer (score 0):

The JRuby Wiki has moved to Kenai. The success stories page can be found here now:

http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/SuccessStories